# Slideshow from scrolling images (Linux or PHP)

Tags: slideshow

I am trying to make a small PHP-based web application creating a slideshow from uploaded images. The images can have different resolutions and proportions (portrait, landscape, square), but the output video should always be 1080x1920. Images with different proportions are scrolling through the video viewport. However, I couldn't find a PHP library for that purpose. As an alternative, I use a Linux console program to be called via shell_exec.

So I tried using dvd-slideshow with the options -mpg -mp4 -s 1080x1920 and an input file listing the images. The input I used is (for each image)
test.jpg:7::scroll:left
followed by
crossfade:2

Unfortunately, the output video still has the wrong resolution and the transitions are triggered too early. For these problems, I'm still unable to find a solution.

Any hints on how to continue (in PHP or on Linux) are greatly appreciated!